# htaccess custom directory for error 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a website where each of my users have a cms installed in a different directory, the structure is like:

```
/ (root)
/cms_user1/
/cms_user1/404.php
/cms_user1/.htaccess
/cms_user2/
/cms_user2/404.php
/cms_user2/.htaccess
```

In each .htaccess file there is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The problem is that in this way the page 404.php isn't loaded on **/cms_client1/404.php** but instead in the root, that is **/404.php**

There is a way to load the 404.php in the user directory automatically, **without specify the name of the directory**?

*PS: the only way i found till now is to specify the directory name in each .htaccess (that in my case is not the best option because i have to edit each htaccess), like this:*

```
ErrorDocument 404 /directory/404.php
```

Answer (score 5):

**Bad News:** Using `ErrorDocument` you cannot do it.
**Good News:** It is possible using `mod_rewrite` rules.

In each of the .htaccess shown in your question you can have a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically/dynamically
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [E=BASE:%2]

# if request is not for a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# if request is not for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# forward it to 404.php in current directory
RewriteRule . %{ENV:BASE}/404.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks, but your code work only on the main directory (example /cms_user1/invalid_dir or /cms_user1/invalid_file.php) but not on subdirectory (example /cms_user1/valid_dir/invalid ). Also, there is a way to handle the ohter errors too (like 400, 401, 403, 500)?

Comment: This rule should work for any 404 path so it will work for `/cms_user1/valid_dir/invalid` also. But yes this won't work for 400, 401, 403, 500 etc.

Comment: i ve try many times but i'm pretty sure that isn't working on `/cms_user1/valid_dir/invalid` in fact in this case i see the "root" 404 page (handled by the root htaccess)

Comment: Do you have any other rule before this rule OR any .htaccess in `/cms_user1/valid_dir/` directory?